# Rails sprockets not pre-compiling assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I have a rails project I moved to a new computer and now Sprockets is not properly compiling the JS files, like it did before.

I am running Rails 3.1.10 and Ruby 1.9.2.

I have a file called pages.js and at the top have the lines

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.qtip.js
//= require fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js
```

When I run `rails server` and navigate to /assets/pages.js it just outputs the code above as raw text, rather then processing and including the files.

I have tried to upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 and that did not help. I also have the following lines in my development.rb file

```
config.assets.compress = false
config.assets.debug = true
```

I also have another project on the same computer, in the same environment, where I am doing the same thing and it works properly. Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: Did your development.log shows any related entries?

Comment: Nope, just the standard
Started GET "/assets/pages.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-05-29 00:59:40 -0400
Served asset /pages.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Comment: Did you add pages.js to `config.assets.precompile`?

Comment: Yep, I did try that and it didn't fix the problem. I have had it there in my production.rb file but it always used to do it automatically in development mode.

Comment: I think Rails only processes the application.js for these require directives, so for your pages.js to be processed, you will need to include pages.js in your application.js and GET application.js instead.

Comment: I don't believe that is the issue. It did work like this before and I am doing the same thing in another project that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that upgrading my version of Rails fixed this problem and now the assets are properly compiled.